# Google+ API: What is 'crosspostSource', and how can one distinguish direct vs indirect shares?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

The [Google+ activities API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities) gives three data relevant to tracing the source of reshares:

- `crosspostSource` If this activity is a crosspost from another system, this property specifies the ID of the original activity.
- `object.actor` If this activity's object is itself another activity (for example, when a person reshares an activity), this property specifies the original activity's actor.
- `object.resharers` People who reshared this activity.

The API isn't very explanatory about this, though.

1. WTF is `crosspostSource`? Sometimes it's the same user's ID + some extra stuff not explained in the api; sometimes it's a number that's not a user ID but again is not explained.
2. How can I distinguish between a *direct* reshare and an *indirect* reshare, in both directions? That is, if A reshares a post, I want to be able to distinguish B (the original author) and C (the person on whose reshare of B's post A clicked 'share'). Likewise, I want to distinguish the opposite direction — people who clicked 'share' from A's post, and those who clicked 'share' on some later reshare of it.

Answer (score 1):

- `crosspostSource` is a holdover from an older version of the ActivityStream spec. It's likely to be renamed to the new value `upstreamDuplicates` some time in the future, so I would not focus on it too much right now. You can read more about it here:  http://activitystrea.ms/specs/json/1.0/#object

It's an opaque unique identifier that's intended to help you de-dupe objects when you're aggregating across multiple sources exposed by many different providers.

- It sounds like you're attempting to get a glimpse into the resharing graph for an activity. Is this right? If so rebuilding the graph for public activities can be accomplished using the API in most cases. It would go something like this:

  1. Starting from an arbitrary reshare in the tree, you'll find the root node (the original post) is the object in the activity. Grab this activity ID.
  2. Now that you have the root node, you can use `people.listByActivities(resharers)` to fetch the first 100 resharers of that activity.
  3. For each of those resharers, fetch their streams. If they publicly shared the activity you should find it. You can then use `people.listByActivities(resharers)` on those activities to work your way down the tree.

This may result in an incomplete graph because you can fetch at most 100 resharers for an activity and if anyone reshares a post to a limited audience you will not be able to discover it via the API.

There may be a better way to work with resharers for your specific situation, though. Could you be more specific about what you intend to do with this resharer data?

Comment: I'd like to get the same data as available in Ripples, yes. (I'm looking at it from a user-centric PoV, not a post-centric one — i.e. using it as part of determining social graph edges.) Therefore, I don't really care so much what someone is resharing; I want to know who they reshared it _from_ (directly, not the OP). Merely knowing who reshared it period won't answer that linkage (and wouldn't eg be enough to make a Ripples).